# Having a <select> whose value is not in the <options>

Tags: php, html, mysql

Lets say I have a database table containing a list of `statuses`.

In my apps form, I have a `<select>` containing options for all of those `statuses` which a user can select.

Now, lets say there is another table called `people` which contains a column for `status` which represents a `status` that was previously selected from the list of `statuses`.

And lets say that I have removed a `status` from my `statuses` table, but there are still database rows for `people` with that removed `status`.

Now in my form, I can no longer pre-select the `<select>` option for that status because it no longer exists in my `statuses` table.

So how would I handle this so that it still pre-selects the removed status in the select? Is my only option to have an `<input type="text">` and then some type of autocompletion like twitter typeahead? And if so, how would I validate this? Would I check if the `status` they enter is what is already there and also in the database table `statuses`?

Any insight would be awesome.

Comment: I think the first thing you should consider is never actually deleting the status from the statuses table, but rather having a column in that table to indicate whether that status is available or not.

Comment: Great idea! (15 chars)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLUTION

Since you are using PHP, you could dynamically append the appropriate status value to the end of your  list based on the person.

SUGGESTIONS

First, you should be using a foreign key to link the status table to your person table, and not just storing the status string in the person table. Creating this relationship would have kept the referential integrity of your tables and prevented you from deleting current statuses in the first place.

Never delete statuses from your table. If you need to remove a status from the list of active statuses, you should add a bit field to your status table called "IsActive" (or something similar). Then you could query `SELECT * FROM status where IsActive=1` for new records while still having all the old values when needed.

Comment: I love this solution too.

Comment: Yes, this should be the accepted solution.  My comment was the lazy way of saying the suggestion.